# Export all data from Firebase Realtime Database

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, database-migration

I would like to get all the data from my Realtime Database (200GB) to migrate it to a different database (PostgreSQL).

I considered:

- creating a script with the Admin SDK and request all the entries, but this would be really slow and would make the database reach the peek (that means slow down all the database).
- using the "Export JSON" function of the console but it is not possible because the size (200GB) is too large.

I just made a manual backup on the console and hopefully I'm going to receive a huge ZIP file that then I will need to manage with a script.

Any other smarter solution?